# Is this flowerpot insert made from asbestos?

Tags: asbestos, old-house, gardening, chemicals

I own three flowerpots with strange white inserts. I haven't bought them in fact they were already part of the 1970 built house when I moved in.
I've heard of asbestos flowerpots but couldn't find anything about inserts.
The material is greyish white and relatively easy to break.

Is it possible that these flowerpots are made out of asbestos?
[image]
[image]
[image]

(I wore a facemask, gloves and a face shield while taking the last picture)

Comment: Send it off to a lab to be tested. It could be or it could be a cement based fibrous product...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until you have it tested, you'll never know. Asbestos doesn't really pose a health risk unless it's frayed or crumbly and the particles are released into the air and you breath them in over a long period of time. If those inserts are outside and you're frequently watering the flowers, you should be fine.  If you decide to just get rid of them as a precautionary measure so you'll sleep better at night (I wore a facemask, gloves and a face shield while taking the last picture), just empty out the dirt and dispose of them properly without breaking them up,

Comment: Be aware that in most places it will be illegal to *"just dispose of them"*, if you suspect they they contain asbestos. In the UK, most councils will accept asbestos at their refuse sites, but it must be wrapped, and you need to call ahead. Not sure what the controls are in Germany, but I'd image they're even more strict.

Comment: Good point, edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did some research and also think it's safe to use them until winter when I get rid of the plants anyway. After this I will properly get rid of them.The regulations in Germany are in fact quiet strict.